# Posting to Facebook from Google Apps Script with images stored in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to post on Facebook. My script works fine as long as the images I want to post are hosted somewhere publicly accessible via URL. However, I run into issues when I try to post images stored in Google Drive.

The Facebook API requires a URL to the image in order to post it, and it doesn't seem to accept file content in the request body for image posts. I've tried using the Drive.Files.get method from the Google Drive API with alt=media to get the actual file content, but this didn't work with the Facebook API.

Is there a way to post an image stored in Google Drive to Facebook using Google Apps Script?

Here's my code for Facebook:

```
function postToFacebook(image_url, caption) {
  const pageAccessToken = getPageAccessToken();

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    'payload' : `url=${encodeURIComponent(image_url)}&caption=${encodeURIComponent(caption)}&published=true&access_token=${pageAccessToken}`
  };
  
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/' + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID + '/photos';
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From `My script works fine as long as the images I want to post are hosted somewhere publicly accessible via URL.`, if you want to use an image file on your Google Drive, how about the following flow?

1. Publicly share the image file.
2. Retrieve the URL of the image file.

When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the file ID of your image file on Google Drive.

```js
function sample() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of your image file.

  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

  const url1 = `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileId}`;
  const url2 = `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${fileId}&sz=w1000`;

  console.log(url1);
  console.log(url2);
}
```

- When this script is run, 2 URLs are shown in the log. Please use one of them by testing them.

#### Note:

- This script supposes that your showing script works. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setSharing(Access,Permission))

Comment: @Khnaz35 As additional information, although I'm not sure about your situation, for example, if the uploaded image can be used even when the image is not publicly shared after the image was uploaded, I think that after the request to the API was finished, the permission of the file can be changed to the unpublic content.